# spinner onItemSelectListener Android - The first item works until selecting a second item

Tags: android, android-spinner, layoutparams

In my application the spinner changes the distance between two TextView. When you select the first item the distance between two TextView is 60 mm. When you select the second item the distance increases to 70mm.

The problem is as follows:
When I create a Toast in response to the selection of each item (which only had put in to check the operation of the Listener), the application works fine and does what it is supposed to do.

However, when I delete the toast, the code stops functioning normally: when I select the first item, nothing happens, when I select the second item, the code of the first item works and when I select the third  item(no code) the code of the second item becomes active.

This is my code:

```
@Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        index = parent.getSelectedItemPosition();
                switch (index){

                    case 0:
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
                        Resources r = getResources();
                        float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_MM, 60,
                                r.getDisplayMetrics());
                        params.setMargins((int) px, 0, 0, 0);
                        tv2.setLayoutParams(params);

                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "posicion: "+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
                        Resources r1 = getResources();
                        float px1 = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_MM, 70,
                                r1.getDisplayMetrics());
                        params1.setMargins((int)px1,0,0,0);
                        tv2.setLayoutParams(params1);
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "posicion: "+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "posicion: "+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;

                }
            }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: use position instead of index.. switch (position){}

Comment: I try with your solution, but is the same result, i need to put a toast in the item code to make it work when is selected at fist time. @Ketan

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of anything that would cause the above code to stop working by simply commenting out the Toasts. Are you certain that simply commenting them out solves the problem?

- If so, try commenting out only one of them at a time and see what
  behavior it exhibits.
- Consider using Log.i() instead.
- Try comparing the values of 'position' and parent.getSelectedItemPosition(). I would have thought that 'position' is what you should be using.
- Check that the indexes of the items inside the Adapter are correct.

Good luck!

Comment: I confirm if a put a toast on the item code, it works fine. And if a not have the Toast in the item code, the item not work until I select another whitout Toast ¬¬.

Comment: As I mentioned, in the Toasts, you are outputting the value of the 'position' variable, but are not using this variable anywhere. Consider either outputting the value of 'index' or using 'position' in the switch statement.

Comment: Yes Ketan also mentioned it so I try, but it works the same way @ThelT

Answer (score 0):

Try out as below it can work this way also.

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            switch (position){

                case 0:
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
                    Resources r = getResources();
                    float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_MM, 60,
                            r.getDisplayMetrics());
                    params.setMargins((int) px, 0, 0, 0);
                    tv2.setLayoutParams(params);

                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "posicion: "+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
                    Resources r1 = getResources();
                    float px1 = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_MM, 70,
                            r1.getDisplayMetrics());
                    params1.setMargins((int)px1,0,0,0);
                    tv2.setLayoutParams(params1);
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "posicion: "+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;

                case 2:
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "posicion: "+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e("Position iss----->",String.valueOf(position));
                    break;

            }
        }

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
}
```

Comment: I do not understand where the log could help, the positions are correct. @GrIsHu

Comment: You will get the log printed in your logcat as you will select the second position from your listview. So that you will get the idea whether its working or not.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

I solve the problem by putting the code of each item on a Runnable.

The code now is as follows:

```
 @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        switch (position){

            case 0:
                tv2.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
                        Resources r = getResources();
                        float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_MM, 60,
                                r.getDisplayMetrics());
                        params.setMargins((int) px, 0, 0, 0);
                        tv2.setLayoutParams(params);
                    }
                }, 300);
                break;
            case 1:
                tv2.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
                        Resources r = getResources();
                        float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_MM, 70,
                                r.getDisplayMetrics());
                        params.setMargins((int) px, 0, 0, 0);
                        tv2.setLayoutParams(params);
                    }
                }, 300);
                break;

            case 2:
                tv2.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT );
                        Resources r = getResources();
                        float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_MM, 30,
                                r.getDisplayMetrics());
                        params.setMargins((int) px, 0, 0, 0);
                        tv2.setLayoutParams(params);
                    }
                }, 300);
                break;
        }
    }
```